# Java boolean returns false even though answer should be correct

Tags: java, boolean, processbuilder, ssid

I'm currently working on a Smartmirror project with a Raspberry Pi Zero W and I need my java program to check the internet connection so that I know wether I can update my weather data. For this method I use the iwgetid command to get the SSID. The problem is the following: I takethe return of the command line and put it into an if block. Even though the return(which I checked is the correct outprint) is correct the boolean returns false as an output.

```
public boolean checkwifi() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    ProcessBuilder ps = new ProcessBuilder("iwgetid");
    ps.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process pr = ps.start();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    line=in.readLine();
    line.trim();

    if(line == "wlan0     ESSID:\"mySSID\"" || line== "wlan0     ESSID:\"mysecondSSID\"" ){
    pr.waitFor();
    in.close();
    return true;    
    }
    else {
        System.err.println(line);
    pr.waitFor();
    in.close();
    return false;

    }
    }
```

This is the output I get from the console:

```
    wlan0     ESSID:"mySSID"
    false
```

Comment: use String.equals("another string"); or String.contains("String");

Comment: I'd recommend trimming and removing white space when comparing Strings like the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(line == "wlan0     ESSID:\"mySSID\"" || line== "wlan0     ESSID:\"mysecondSSID\"" )` compares the reference of `line` to the string, and they are different.

Use `line.equals("wlan0     ESSID:\"mySSID\"") || line.equals("wlan0     ESSID:\"mysecondSSID\"")` to compare the actual value of the Strings.